# OPC-da connector for Kafka - available solutions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, opc-da

Is there any out of the box solution for connecting opc-da to Kafka? I’m looking to get data from and opc-da server into apache Flink

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949669/1790688

> You can use the OPC Router with the [Kafka
> Plug-In](https://www.opc-router.com/apache-kafka-opc-router-plug-in-en/)
> to stream [OPC UA or OPC
> Classic](https://www.opc-router.com/2-opc-ua-client_en/) data to
> Kafka.
>
> The OPC Router is listed as [official solution in the confluent
> hub](https://www.confluent.de/hub/inray/opc-router-4)